# Application.International xlDecimalSeparator workaround

Tags: excel, vba

I have to make an table via copy_paste value from one cell. Then, those values will be multiplied with a value from another cell. The problem is "the xlDecimalSeparator". When It is set to be "." it is ok. When it is used "," the problem starts. (I have an dutch settings). I try to make an workaround: declare cell as text, then replace "," with ".", put values in cell then format cell as number. Everithing is working well except that in the end to have the correct value I have to double click on cell + enter to have the result the formula otherwise I just have something like this "=3*$D$1" not 6 (the result of the function).

so my code:

```
Sub Copy_Cell_test()

Dim my_range As Range
Dim strDecimal As String
Dim c As Variant

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

strDecimal = Application.International(xlDecimalSeparator)
If strDecimal = "," Then strDecimal = "."

Set my_range = Worksheets("sheet_test").Range("A2:H111")

    With my_range
        For Each c In my_range
            If Not c.Value = "" Then
                c.NumberFormat = "@"
                c.Value = Replace(c.Value, ",", strDecimal)
                c.Value = "=" & c.Value& & "*$D$1"
                  If Application.International(xlDecimalSeparator) = "," Then
                      c.Value = Replace(c.Value, strDecimal, ",")
                  End If
                c.NumberFormat = "0.00"" €/lm"""
                'c.Value = c.Value <<< Here I have error if "," is set
            End If
        Next c
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

How can I fix it? I try send key F2 + [ENTER] but it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me with `FormulaLocal`.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Copy_Cell_test()
    Dim my_range As Range
    Dim c As Range
    Dim formulaText As String

    On Error GoTo handleErr

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set my_range = Worksheets("sheet_test").Range("A2:H111")

    With my_range
        For Each c In my_range
            If Not c.Value = "" Then
                formulaText = "=" & c.Value & "*$D$1"
                c.FormulaLocal = formulaText
                c.NumberFormat = "0.00"" €/lm"""
            End If
        Next c
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

handleErr:
    If Err.Number = 0 Then Exit Sub
    MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```

Comment: And my ```Application.International(xlDecimalSeparator)``` equals to ```,``` as well. If the code does not work for you, please post sample of data you are working with. HTH